# file transfer using batch file or shell script

Tags: linux, bash, window

I want to transfer .txt file from window system to linux server using wan ip (using root name and password) using batch file is that any options.

either  any option from linux to window file access using shell script please reply me.

Thanks
HM Suthar

Comment: Do u have a FTP Server in your Linux box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for this. Download it, then create a .bat file with this in:

```
@echo off
start """ "C:\Location\To\pscp" -r -pw PASSWORD C:\File\To\Upload.txt root@IP.AD.DR.ESS:/path/to/upload/to
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually deal with it from the source server rather than the receiving server but it doesnt matter.  The following is a very basic linux shell script for FTP'ing

```
#/usr/bin/ksh

FTPFILE=ftpfile.txt
FTPDIR=directorytomoveto

ftp -nv <<EOF 
open ip_address_goes_here
user username password
prompt
binary
lcd $FTPDIR
get $FTPFILE
bye
EOF

exit 0
```

Bare in mind this is incredibly basic and involves hardcoding the username/password into the file.

As it is a WAN do you really want to use FTP.

Here are a few useful links which contain much much more information:

http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ftp.htm

take a look at the man page for ftp on linux